# Inline Editing using Mysql PDO, jQuery, AJAX, and PHP 7.0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I can find no info on this question that specifically address the issue,
and I've spent 2 weeks researching the question. I will try to show
the code to support the question.
Below is the code that works.
The goal is to inline edit table data using `<td contenteditable="true"`
and onBlur element properties.
I can make this work using mysqli but not PDO prepared statements.

This code works perfectly. The example is from Vincy in India,  and it
 works with all my databases, as expected, perfectly.  I however, want
 to use PDO if possible, but I have failed in all  attempts to
 transpose this process to PDO and AJAX together.  I suspect at this
 point that with PDO, the string has to be json encoded/decoded to
 work, so that the proper PDO update query can be  processed.I'm hoping
 that this will help someone else also.

HTML Table on index.php

```
<tr class="table-row">
  <td><?php echo $k+1; ?></td>
  <td contenteditable="true"onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')"onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["question"]; ?></td>
  <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'answer','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')"onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["answer"];   ?></td>
</tr>
```

AJAX jQuery functions below HTML table. Using CDN version 3.3.1 jQuery

```
<script>
function showEdit(editableObj) {
  $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");
}
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
  $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(loaderIcon.gif)no-repeat right");
  $.ajax({
    url: "saveedit.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:'column='+column+'&editval='+$(editableObj).text+'&id='+id,
    success: function(data){
      $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

db connection for mysqli: this works perfectly

```
<?php
class DBController {
  private $host = "localhost";
  private $user = "root";
  private $password = "";
  private $database = "crosscon";
  private $conn;
  function __construct() {
    $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
  }
  function connectDB() {
    $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
    return $conn;
  }
  function runQuery($query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $resultset[] = $row;
    }
    if(!empty($resultset))
    return $resultset;
  }
  function numRows($query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
    $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    return $rowcount;
  }
  function executeUpdate($query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
    return $result;
  }
}
?>
```

mysqli processing page works perfectly.
Processing php page.There are no errors. Mysqli works and updates the database. AJAX is passing a string to the update query without any additional handling with json encode or decode.It simply is working as it should.

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$result = $db_handle->executeUpdate("UPDATE blogs set " .    POST["column"] . " = '".$_POST["editval"]."' WHERE  id=".$_POST["id"]);
?>
```

page:process.php

```
<?php
require_once("dbPDO.php");
$column  = $_POST['column'];
$editval = $_POST['editval'];
$id      = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE accounts SET column=?, editval=? WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$column, $editval, $id]);
var_dump($stmt);
?>
```

This produces a mysql error: C:\wamp64\www\ajax5\editAccounts.php:10:null
So I'm not passing any values to the process.php. The same code works perfectly in mysqli, with a mysli connection object processing it. Same language so this is logical. However, the analagous code in PDO fails, even thought the database table renders,and the network passes the '`column`, `editvalue`, and `id`as a string in both cases. In the mysqli instance, the AJAX is being sent as a string and processed as a string. PDO process

In the PDO instance, I suspect that it now has to be sent as a json array as a string, decoded on the processing page using json decode function(???), so that the variables can be set and consumed by the PDO update query. I can most likely work through this, however, in short after two weeks, I would like to know if it is even possible. I have the template, I have 90% of this working, I have just hit the wall in this project. I very much want to do inline editing, as I think the users really like it,
and I like the security of PDO, but if it is not possible to use jQuery and
asynchronous events with prepared statements, I have to rethink my entire approach to my application.
1. Is my assumption correct that PDO must consume a json array docoded from the AJAX code on the sending page?
2. Is there an example of how to do this in the AJAX code and then decode it on the receiving page so it can be consumed by the receiving page, and then the success string sent back to the receiving page?
Thank you

Comment: `This produces a mysql error: C:\wamp64\www\ajax5\editAccounts.php:10:null` is PDO in exception mode?  `$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`  You should have a lot more then `null` right now that could be anything....

Comment: `AJAX is passing a string` every request on the web is technically a string.  That HTML code that makes up your page, that download you did, that image you viewed. That CSS all stings.  What makes them special is the Headers.  In modern browsers as long as you dont do `JSON.stringify` or set the datatype to something weird you should be ok.

Comment: ArtisticPhoenix: ATTR_ERRMODE is on and I get mysql stack trace errors, but I know what they mean, and I'm not passing the values expected for the query on the processing page. I didn't add the image as I thought it redundant. But I can!

Comment: It might help, just make sure your connection string is not in the stack trace, sometimes PDO::construct will have it as arguments in there...  The DB can be generic a good example is I had a `unknown table for user` turns out the user didnt have permission to that DB.... etc.  If you pass those arguments to PHP, did you try simply `print_r($_POST)` to see what you have in PHP, you can check the f12 debug in the browser, it should be in the XHR request as the response etc.  or as data in your call back.

Comment: have you tried `data:{column:column,editval:$(editableObj).text,id:id}` I don't know if it makes a difference but I never used the other way in like the last 8 years or so ... lol ... this way always works for me so I never bothered, object is easier anyway.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: I tried the curly braces. No effect.

Comment: @phpDelusions With help transposing the mysqli to a pdo query, and changing the AJAX from object to json text, I was able to make inline editing safe from sql injection.I would like to thank  for the gracious help.